# Is it possible to create table with pagination in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to create a table with 100 rows and 4 columns in jquery mobile.Is it possible to create such a table in jquery mobile with pagination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use plugins for pagination of table with jquery,
check out this link http://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-easy-table-pagination/

It also has a working jsfiddle demo..